# How to extract covariance (error) matrix of independent parameters x,y from covariance matrix of dependent parameters x,y,z?

Tags: covariance, independence, matrix

Suppose I have a covariance (error) matrix `C_xyz` for system with 3 parameters: `x, y, z`.

Then it appears that `x, y` and `z` depends on each other:

```
det(C_xyz) = 0
ax + by + z = 0
```

How to find covariance matrix `C_xy` of independent `x,y` parameters knowing covariance `C_xyz` and function `a,b`?

Comment: You could begin with a Gaussian random vector and linear $f$, i.e. $f= ax + b y+ cz$, which will help you to clarify the assumptions: you
need $c \neq 0$.  In this case, block matrix computations will give you the answer.  You may then carefully extend your result for an $f$ is close enough to a linear function by relying on a linear approximation.

Comment: @Yves, ok, I simplified the function. What next? What is block matrix computations?

Comment: Sorry, it is much simpler than I suggested. Your matrix is simply the $2 \times 2$
submatrix of the whole $3 \times 3$. Hopefully the submatrix is non-degenerated while the large one has rank $\leq 2$.